# Не работает метод predict() Keras models

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Обучил свёрточную нейросеть и записал результаты в файл .hdf5
При попытке распознать изображение, на методе predict() выдает ошибку Traceback (most recent call last).

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


classes = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

model = load_model('model-dense-17-0.00010-1.0000.hdf5')
# ['model_weights', 'optimizer_weights']
# print(model.summary())

img_path = '0.06170.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(56, 56), color_mode="grayscale")
# Преобразуем картинку в массив
x = image.img_to_array(img)
# Меняем форму массива в плоский вектор
x = x.reshape(1, 3136)
# Инвертируем изображение
x = 255 - x
# Нормализуем изображение
x /= 255

prediction = model.predict(x)
print(prediction)

# prediction = np.argmax(prediction)
# print("Номер класса:", prediction)
# print("Название класса:", classes[prediction])
```

[model-dense-17-0.00010-1.0000.hdf5](https://my-files.su/0g51rs)

[0.06170.jpg](https://my-files.su/7km2p4)

Полный код ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/3_load_hdf5.py", line 27, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict(x)
  File "D:\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 88, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1268, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = predict_function(iterator)
  File "D:\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "D:\python\eager\def_function.py", line 506, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "D:\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "D:\python\eager\function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "D:\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "D:\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    D:\python\keras\engine\training.py:1147 predict_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    D:\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    D:\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    D:\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    D:\python\keras\engine\training.py:1122 predict_step  **
        return self(x, training=False)
    D:\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:886 __call__
        self.name)
    D:\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:180 assert_input_compatibility
        str(x.shape.as_list()))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 3136]
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы __без явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Укажите в вопросе полный текст ошибки (`error traceback`)